# How to attach the various ground pins of a TDA7560 amplifier?

Tags: grounding, power-amplifier

I'm now about to integrate the [TDA7560](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00001962-1795702.pdf) amplifier into my audio circuitry, but I'm still not sure about what the various ground pins of the amp to. There are a bunch of them:

- 1× TAB (pin #1)
- 4× P-GNDs (pins #2, #8, #18, #24)
- 1× S-GND (pin #13)
- 1× AC-GND (pin #16; via 470n cap)

[image: Schema from datasheet]

As I am already aware that not all GND connections are the same (in this particular case I've got the external +15 V supply with 2 output pins, OUT+ and OUT–), I gave all GND pins, which are declared as *power GND* ones a GNDPWR symbol:

[image: Kicad schematic]

Then I attached GNDPWR to the negative output of the +15 V supply:

[image: Kicad power flags]

Is anything wrong with what I've designed or is there any room for improvements?

Comment: What does the data sheet tell you?

Comment: Did you read the data sheet very carefully, especially about ground?

Comment: The datasheet (see link above) does not tell very much about how to ground the chip correctly. In fact, the schematic always uses the same ground symbol (no digital, analog, or power ground).